# Wanted to get output of databricks activity in the ADF pipeline so that I can use those output parameter in further ADF Activity

Tags: azure-data-factory, azure-databricks

I am having a data bricks activity which I am using in ADF and I wanted to get the run output in further activity's like there is one file which I am using in data bricks to get all the days from the column and now I wanted to get all these days as output in data factory parameter so that I can use these day's as parameters in pre-copy script to delete the specific day of data.

Answer (score 1):

If the parameter you want to pass is small, you can do so by using: `dbutils.notebook.exit("returnValue")` (see this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/transform-data-databricks-notebook#passing-parameters-between-notebooks-and-data-factory)).

For a larger set of inputs, I would write the input values from Databricks into a file and iterate (`ForEach`) over the different values in ADF.

Answer (score 1):

another option would be to return the list of days as a json string and then use that for example:

```
import json

dates = ['2017-12-11', '2017-12-10', '2017-12-09', '2017-12-08', '2017-12-07']
return_json = json.dumps(dates)

dbutils.notebook.exit(return_json)
```

You can then either operate on the output using a [foreach Activity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-for-each-activity) or do additional processing using the [Append Variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-append-variable-activity) or 
[Set Variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-set-variable-activity) Activities

Hope this helps